# Mention bot for respond discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command when you mention the bot, it will send a message saying “Slash Command: /help”. I have tried to make it and I tried to find an answer but I can’t find anything that works for me.

Here is the code (I use the code in `index.js`):

```js
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;

    if (message.content.includes("@here") || message.content.includes("@everyone") || message.type == "REPLY") return false;

    if (message.mentions.has(client.user.id)) {
        message.channel.send("Hello there!");
    }
});
```

I added the `GatewayIntentBits.Guilds` intent to my intents array. I don't get any errors, it just doesn’t work.

Comment: What intents have you enabled?

Comment: Im using the GatewayIntentBits.Guilds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only using the `GatewayIntentBits.Guilds` intent, you won't receive messages. You'll also need to add `GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages`. It allows you to receive messages if the `client`/bot is mentioned.

If you also want to receive the message content when the bot is not mentioned, you'll also need to add `GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent`. However, if you only want to see if the bot is mentioned, adding `GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages` to your intents array will be enough.

Comment: Thanks the problem was in the intents

Comment: So my answer is correct and you accepted one that's incorrect?

Comment: No it wasn’t incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use RegExp, it would be done like this:

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.content.includes("@here") || message.content.includes("@everyone") || message.type == "REPLY") return;

    if (message.content.match(new RegExp(`^<@!?${client.user.id}>( |)$`))) {
        message.channel.send("Hello there!");
    }
});
```

The RegExp object is used for matching text with a pattern. So if it matches what you've typed (in this case the @bot ), send the message

Comment: No it doesn’t work but thanks

Comment: So i make it work i had some problems with the intents and thank you

Comment: @ImAnthox So why do you upvote and accept an incorrect answer?

Comment: It wasn’t incorrect

Comment: How is this not incorrect if you had issues with intents? `message.mentions.has` works perfectly fine if the correct intents are enabled so there is no need to use a new regex? Especially if this regex only works if the message only mentions the bot and there is nothing else in that message.